# My show segue isn't pushing to the next screen, there's just a weird blank space popup that comes up. I don't get how this is happening

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I've included a picture of what I see when I press either the "Sign-Up" button or the "Log In" button.

Each button has a `show` segue-action that should take me to a separate page, but it just shows this weird popup. Any ideas of what could be making this happen?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post any relevant code or Storyboard screenshots.

Comment: Please see how to add a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So I've reproduced the issue. The segue works fine at first but when I add a second swift view controller document, in my case a SignUpViewController.swift document, and add the custom class to the view on the storyboard that's what I get in the screenshot.